# Google Cloud Text to Speech API not recognizing API key

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to receive results from The Google Cloud Text To Speech API, as per the demo on the official website under "Show json": https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech by running this code:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize', json={
  "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
    "pitch": 0,
    "speakingRate": 1
  },
  "input": {
    "text": "Google Cloud Text-to-Speech enables developers to synthesize natural-sounding speech with 100+ voices, available in multiple languages and variants. It applies DeepMind’s groundbreaking research in WaveNet and Google’s powerful neural networks to deliver the highest fidelity possible. As an easy-to-use API, you can create lifelike interactions with your users, across many applications and devices."
  },
  "voice": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "name": "en-US-Wavenet-D"
  }
})

print(r.json())
```

However I am receiving this error message:

```
{'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The request is missing a valid API key.', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}
```

Despite having done everything for the setup with the account, API key and environment variable exactly as detailed here: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/before-you-begin

So I am at a bit of a loss for what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As the API response says, your request is missing the API key.

To fix this, you can either inject an `Authorization` bearer token in your request [the value is the access token, the output of `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`]

-OR-

(as I can see you're using python)I suggest you use the client library to read your credentials automatically (since you've set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable)

Installing via pip: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-texttospeech`

[Read more about using the client library here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-client-libraries#python)